# Emulating lambdas in C++03 for flow-control purposes in macros

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, macros, c++03

I have some existing code in a header file which needs to be useable in the context of C++03 & C++11

It defines a macro `TABORT` that takes in a `printf`-style format string & arguments to be formatted using that string, prints the result to `stdout`, and then calls `std::abort`

Essentially, something similar to

```
#define TABORT(...) do { fprintf(stderr, "Aborting at %s:%d for reason: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); std::abort(); } while(0)
```

I wanted to add some logic to catch the case where evaluating `__VA_ARGS__` would throw an exception, preventing the call to `std::abort`. For example, in the following:

```
if (SomethingReallyBadHappened())
    TABORT("Aborting because %s", GetReallyBadDetails().c_str());
```

if `GetReallyBadDetails` throws an exception, I want to ensure that abort gets called (*here*, not after some exception unwinding).

So, I did something like:

```
#define TABORT(...) do { fprintf(stderr, "Aborting at %s:%d for reason: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); try { fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); } catch (...) { fprintf(stderr, "<Failed to evaluate abort message>\n"); } std::abort(); } while(0)
```

But this is causing the [C4714 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/a98sb923(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in visual studio when the macro is used in functions marked `__forceinline`, probably due to

> In some cases, the compiler will not inline a particular function for
> mechanical reasons. For example, the compiler will not inline:
>
> - A function with a try (C++ exception handling) statement.

So, to avoid that warning (& to keep inlining functions which were previously determined to need inlining *inlined* [I *hope* this was done alongside profiling...]), I was thinking to do something like

```
// In header

// Assume this is like std::function except construction from a lambda can't throw
template <typename Sig>
class function_ref;
using PrintAbortMsg = function_ref<void(const char*)>;
void [[noreturn]] do_tabort(const char* file, int line, function_ref<void(PrintAbortMsg &)> msgGenerator) noexcept;
#define TABORT(...) do_tabort(__FILE__, __LINE__, [&](PrintAbortMsg& print) { print(SprintfToStdString(__VA_ARGS__).c_str()); })

// In cpp

void do_tabort(const char* file, int line, function_ref<void(PrintAbortMsg&)> msgGenerator) noexcept
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Aborting at %s:%d for reason: ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    try
    {
        msgGenerator([](const char* msg) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg); });
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "<Failed to evaluate abort message>\n");
    }
    std::abort();
}
```

Which I *think* would work in the context of C++11, but I'm not sure how to do something which will work for for C++03. There are existing usages of the macro which I don't want to touch.

Comment: A lambda is, essentially, an anonymous `struct` type, with members representing (any) captured data and an `operator()` with arguments representing the "body" of the lambda function. Before C++11you can crudely replicate something in a macro by defining such a struct, creating an instance, and calling its `operator()`.  Both the struct type and the instance need unique names (e.g. by using token pasting with something like `__LINE__` (unique to a line of code in a source file, but not between source files, as long as you don't monkey with `#line` extensions supported by some preprocessors)

Comment: @Peter - The issue here is how do I transparently execute the expressions passed as parameters to the macro in the context of a function separate to the one which invoked the macro? Just thinking about it more now, I'm thinking it might be impossible in general without C++ lambdas, since those expressions can refer to something in the local scope of where the macro is used

Comment: Instead of emulating just make "lambda" structs manually. You can type a lambda in at [C++ insights](https://cppinsights.io/) and it will show you the code like this : https://cppinsights.io/s/800e1bd2

Comment: @Bmwat  With that comment you've just demonstrated that you don't understand how lambdas work. Expressions in a lambda function don't refer to something in the local scope of where the macro is used. A lambda is just a notational shorthand for creating a data structure populated with data (or references) during its construction.   The `operator()` of that struct accesses members of the struct itself - and those members hold either the values of, or pointers/references to, the so-called captured variables.   You're treating it as some magic which can't be emulated, and you're missing the point.

Comment: @Peter No, I understand that lambdas are just syntax sugar, my problem is that I don't want to modify existing usages of the macro, so if one of the parameters refers to something in the local scope where the macro was used, there's no way, AFAICT, to make that same text 'mean' the same thing when injected into functor method I defined myself. I need lambdas' 'capture' feature/syntax-sugar

Comment: For example, consider `void foo() { int a = bar(); if (a) TABORT("Error %d", a); }`. If I try to define my own functor, the only thing I have to work with is the text `a`. Inside `operator()`, using `a` directly would simply result in a compiler error (undefined reference). Is there some way of fixing this problem (within the preprocessor) that I'm missing? Note that the macro can take 1 or more parameters that can have any type passable through a `...`

Comment: You need 2 distinc set of parameters: capture list and call arguments. I can't imagine to have both in the same macro.

Comment: The compiler magic that you cannot replicate is hidden inside `[&]`, the lambda preamble with implicit capture. The compiler would look inside expressions in `__VA_ARGS__`, figure out which variables are mentioned there, capture those into data members of the lambda objects, and then re-assemble the expressions over those data members in the `operator()`. I don't see how you can pull that off in a macro without lambdas - preprocessor cannot x-ray into the expressions this way.

Comment: I see you have rejected the answer whereby the macro would instantiate a class that calls `abort()` in its destructor. But why? Your stated ultimate goal is not to emulate a lambda - that's just a means to an end - but to ensure `abort()` is called even if something evaluated within the macro throws an exception. A scope guard would do that nicely. So, in what way does this solution fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: "my problem is that I don't want to modify existing usages of the macro" I think that your problem is not that, but rather having to deal with C++03, a truly awful and borderline unusable language.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Actually I didn't realize that putting the call to abort in the destructor would work, thanks for that, I just tried it, and it prevents the warning! If you want to make an answer (or if whoever created the answer I unwisely rejected wants to un-delete it), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working too hard. Just write a class that calls `abort()` in its destructor. Create an instance of that class right after the opening brace in the macro. It will be destroyed and call `abort` at the closing brace, whether the block is exited normally or via exception. As in

```
struct AbortWhenDestroyed {
  ~AbortWhenDestroyed() { abort(); }
};

#define TABORT(...) do { \
  AbortWhenDestroyed abort_me; \
  fprintf(stderr, "Aborting at %s:%d for reason: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
  fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); \
} while(0)
```

The search term for further research is "scope guard". See also: [`std::experimental::scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit)

---

You can also make this class print `<Failed to evaluate abort message>`, as in your try/catch example. Along these lines:

```
struct AbortWhenDestroyed {
  ~AbortWhenDestroyed() {
      if (!normal_exit) {
        fprintf(stderr, "<Failed to evaluate abort message>\n");
      }
      abort();
  }
  bool normal_exit = false;
};

#define TABORT(...) do { \
  AbortWhenDestroyed abort_me; \
  fprintf(stderr, "Aborting at %s:%d for reason: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
  fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); \
  abort_me.normal_exit = true;
} while(0)
```

If evaluating `__VA_ARGS__` throws an exception, then the line `abort_me.normal_exit = true;` won't be executed, and the destructor would emit the warning before aborting.